# Re-encode and stream UDP TV Channels

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, udp, streaming, television

I used from long time mumudvb and one dvb-t pci card to stream TV channels on my network. This is working fine but I've recently add another player that is less powerfull than others so I want to re-encode the video stream.

This is my input stream video :

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'udp://@239.1.4.1:8200':
  Duration: N/A, start: 53843.533922, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1025 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : M6
      service_provider: Multi4
    Stream #0:0[0x78]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [   SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x82](fra): Audio: eac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 192 kb/s
    Stream #0:2[0x83](qad): Audio: eac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
    Stream #0:3[0x84](qaa): Audio: eac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Stream #0:4[0x8c](fra): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006) (hearing impaired)
    Stream #0:5[0x8d](fra): Subtitle: dvb_subtitle ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:6[0xaa]: Unknown: none ([5][0][0][0] / 0x0005)
    Stream #0:7[0xab]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)
```

ffmpeg version 3.0.1 
Running on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

And this is my command line to run ffmpeg :

```
ffmpeg -i udp://@239.1.4.1:8200 -qscale:v:0 7 -c:v:0 mpeg4 -b:v:0 4000k -minrate:v 0 -maxrate:v 4000k -bufsize:v 5000k -s hd720 -c:a copy -f mpegts udp://239.1.24.1:8200?pkt_size=1316
```

But when I do this, I've got errors like this on my VLC player :

```
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output debug: inserting 35549 zeroes
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output warning: playback too early (-55552): down-sampling
[00007f2ff3adc4c0] xcb vout display debug: display is visible
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output debug: resampling stopped (drift: -13228 us)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 33 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 2 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 4 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 0 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 22 ms)
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output warning: playback too early (-40559): down-sampling
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 8 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 13 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 3 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 3 ms)
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output debug: resampling stopped (drift: 1666 us)
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output warning: playback way too early (-130510): playing silence
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output debug: inserting 6264 zeroes
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 13 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 15 ms)
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output warning: playback too early (-41304): down-sampling
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 10 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 54 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 15 ms)
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output warning: timing screwed (drift: -105734 us): stopping resampling
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output warning: playback too early (-105702): down-sampling
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 10 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 10 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 60 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 20 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 14 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output debug: picture might be displayed late (missing 13 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 61 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 25 ms)
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output debug: resampling stopped (drift: -40141 us)
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output warning: playback too early (-40140): down-sampling
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output warning: playback too late (91622): up-sampling
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output debug: resampling stopped (drift: 120767 us)
[00007f2ff3ad64c0] main audio output warning: playback too late (120781): up-sampling
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 64 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 25 ms)
[00007f300dd870c0] main video output warning: picture is too late to be displayed (missing 31 ms)
```

On web-plugin VLC media player - 3.0.3 Vetinari running on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

This is resulting on many glitch on VLC video and after some times audio and video become de-synchronised.

For some reasons, I can't update VLC / FFMPEG / Ubuntu

Can you help me with that ?

Thanks in advance for your time !

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a different streamer, a good one, stable and that does UDP streaming is https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash-live-source-simulator . Editing for instance this variables:

```
DEFAULT_AVAILABILITY_STARTTIME_IN_S = time.time()
DEFAULT_AVAILABILITY_TIME_OFFSET_IN_S = 300
DEFAULT_TIMESHIFT_BUFFER_DEPTH_IN_SECS = 300
DEFAULT_SHORT_MINIMUM_UPDATE_PERIOD_IN_S = 10
```

By tuning these variables you can make sure the audio/video are in sync and that pictures don't arrive late. Beware this needs an MPD file to work.